# EAGLE 7.7 do not fill GND polygon

Tags: ground, eaglecad, ground-plane

[image: PCB]

Adding a polygon GND, but it not going to fill at all. Ratsnest - not helping. Orhans also not helping. Any idea?

[image: NET CLASSES]
[image: Design Rules]
[image: Net class desc]

[image]

Comment: Try filling on the non-component layer just to prove it works.

Comment: it doesn't work either

Comment: Did you use the "name"-function to name the polygon? You shouldn't name it from the property dialog. Does you ERC on schematic side give related errors? You have the polygon assigned to "0 GND"-net, but you actually only have "0 default"?

Comment: Well, now you've simplified the problem; you've ruled out the fact that the problem isn't due to not enough room on the top layer. Persevere on the clear underside layer until you find a fix then, apply to the top layer.

Comment: Yes, I named via Name function. Changed it to "0 default" - also not working

Answer (score 0):

Eagle can be set to not fill in polygons when the ratsnets command is issued. This can be a blessing when you have dozens of polygons in a big design and you dont want to wait multiple seconds on each ratsnest.

[image]

settings>misc>Ratsnest processes polygons

what you can also try is to render the gerber via the cam processor because the fill of the polygon is not stored in the polygon itself, and the cam processor will do this for you.

This is in eagle 9, your older version might have the button somewhere else

Also keep 'orphans'  enabled if you are really not sure. This way eagle will fill the polygon even if it cant find anything to connect to or if it falls outside of the board dimension layer. Disable it when you are done to avoid flying bits of copper

Comment: unfortunately this also did not helped

Comment: What about the other part? If you render the board in the CAM processor, is the fill visible? If everything fails, try deleting the eaglerc settings file (on windows: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Eagle\settings\<version>\eaglerc). This will delete most user settings, they will revert to default when you relaunch eagle. Its wise to keep a backup of that file before deleting....

Comment: Tried both - not helped

Comment: I had a bug once where round-up errors in the polygon edge coordinates made it so that eagle didn't recognize the polygon edges where connected, and the polygon was only partly drawn. So try 'simple'  90 degree corners, while keeping on a consistent routing grid, and check that the coordinates of the line ends match which each other.
Finally, can you attach a screenshot of your layer settings, including the fill styles for the copper layers and your color palette? The polygon pour might just be invisible. But then again, that should still make it appear in the CAM processor